# Wordpress Custom Post URL Rewrite Numbers

Tags: wordpress

So I have a couple of Custom post types with the same post names in each:

```
Post Type: Service (http://www.example.com/service/skincare)

Post Type: Price (http://www.example.com/price/skincare-2)

Post Type: FAQ (http://www.example.com/faq/skincare-3)
```

I want to rewrite the URLs to eliminate the numbers, so it will end up like this:

```
Post Type: Service (http://www.example.com/service/skincare)

Post Type: Price (http://www.example.com/price/skincare)

Post Type: FAQ (http://www.example.com/faq/skincare)
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Here is ALL my custom post code:

```
/*
* ========================================================================
* Custom Post Types
* ========================================================================
*/

// Create 1 Custom Post type for a Demo, called HTML5-Blank
add_action('init', 'create_post_type_html5'); // Add our HTML5 Blank Custom Post Type
function create_post_type_html5()
{
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'html5-blank'); // Register Taxonomies for   Category
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'html5-blank');
register_post_type('html5-blank', // Register Custom Post Type
    array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __('Services', 'html5blank'), // Rename these to suit
        'singular_name' => __('Services', 'html5blank'),
        'add_new' => __('Add New', 'html5blank'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Services', 'html5blank'),
        'edit' => __('Edit', 'html5blank'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Services', 'html5blank'),
        'new_item' => __('New Services', 'html5blank'),
        'view' => __('View Services', 'html5blank'),
        'view_item' => __('View Services', 'html5blank'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Services', 'html5blank'),
        'not_found' => __('No Servicess found', 'html5blank'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Service\'s found in Trash', 'html5blank')
      ),
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'service','with_front' => false),
    'public' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true, // Allows your posts to behave like Hierarchy Pages
    'has_archive' => true,
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'excerpt',
        'thumbnail'
    ), // Go to Dashboard Custom HTML5 Blank post for supports
    'can_export' => true, // Allows export in Tools > Export
    'taxonomies' => array(
        'post_tag',
        'category'
    ) // Add Category and Post Tags support
   ));


    }



    add_action('init', 'create_post_type_html5_2'); // Add our HTML5 Blank Custom Post Type
    function create_post_type_html5_2()
    {
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'html5-blank2'); // Register Taxonomies for Category
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'html5-blank2');
register_post_type('html5-blank2', // Register Custom Post Type
    array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __('Prices', 'html5blank2'), // Rename these to suit
        'singular_name' => __('Prices', 'html5blank2'),
        'add_new' => __('Add New', 'html5blank2'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Prices', 'html5blank2'),
        'edit' => __('Edit', 'html5blank2'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Prices', 'html5blank2'),
        'new_item' => __('New Prices', 'html5blank2'),
        'view' => __('View Prices', 'html5blank2'),
        'view_item' => __('View Prices', 'html5blank2'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Prices', 'html5blank2'),
        'not_found' => __('No Prices found', 'html5blank2'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Price\'s found in Trash', 'html5blank2')
    ),
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'prices','with_front' => false),
    'public' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true, // Allows your posts to behave like Hierarchy Pages
    'has_archive' => true,
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'excerpt',
        'thumbnail'
    ), // Go to Dashboard Custom HTML5 Blank post for supports
    'can_export' => true, // Allows export in Tools > Export
    'taxonomies' => array(
        'post_tag',
        'category'
    ) // Add Category and Post Tags support
   ));


   }




   add_action('init', 'create_post_type_html5_3'); // Add our HTML5 Blank Custom Post Type
   function create_post_type_html5_3()
    {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'html5-blank3'); // Register Taxonomies for Category
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'html5-blank3');
    register_post_type('html5-blank3', // Register Custom Post Type
    array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __('FAQ', 'html5blank3'), // Rename these to suit
        'singular_name' => __('FAQ', 'html5blank3'),
        'add_new' => __('Add New', 'html5blank3'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New FAQ', 'html5blank3'),
        'edit' => __('Edit', 'html5blank3'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit FAQ', 'html5blank3'),
        'new_item' => __('New FAQ', 'html5blank3'),
        'view' => __('View FAQ', 'html5blank3'),
        'view_item' => __('View FAQ', 'html5blank3'),
        'search_items' => __('Search FAQ', 'html5blank3'),
        'not_found' => __('No Prices found', 'html5blank3'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No FAQ\'s found in Trash', 'html5blank3')
    ),
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'faq','with_front' => false),
    'public' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true, // Allows your posts to behave like Hierarchy Pages
    'has_archive' => true,
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'excerpt',
        'thumbnail'
    ), // Go to Dashboard Custom HTML5 Blank post for supports
    'can_export' => true, // Allows export in Tools > Export
    'taxonomies' => array(
        'post_tag',
        'category'
    ) // Add Category and Post Tags support
    ));


    }



    add_action('init', 'create_post_type_html5_4'); // Add our HTML5 Blank Custom Post Type
    function create_post_type_html5_4()
    {
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'html5-blank4'); // Register Taxonomies for Category
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'html5-blank4');
register_post_type('html5-blank4', // Register Custom Post Type
    array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __('Before and After', 'html5blank4'), // Rename these to suit
        'singular_name' => __('Before and After', 'html5blank4'),
        'add_new' => __('Add New', 'html5blank4'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Before and After', 'html5blank4'),
        'edit' => __('Edit', 'html5blank4'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Before and After', 'html5blank4'),
        'new_item' => __('New Before and After', 'html5blank4'),
        'view' => __('View Before and After', 'html5blank4'),
        'view_item' => __('View Before and After', 'html5blank4'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Before and After', 'html5blank4'),
        'not_found' => __('No Before and After found', 'html5blank4'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Before and After\'s found in Trash', 'html5blank4')
        ),
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'before-and-after','with_front' => false),
    'public' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true, // Allows your posts to behave like Hierarchy Pages
    'has_archive' => true,
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'excerpt',
        'thumbnail'
    ), // Go to Dashboard Custom HTML5 Blank post for supports
    'can_export' => true, // Allows export in Tools > Export
    'taxonomies' => array(
        'post_tag',
        'category'
    ) // Add Category and Post Tags support
));


 }
```

Comment: Have you tried to simply remove the number from each posts` permalink?

Comment: Yep, always defaults back to the number... :(

Comment: That's strange. I attempted to add a post with the same name to multiple custom post types and I didn't add any numbers at all.  Could you post your code for your custom post types?

Comment: Custom post type looks fine.  The post types you mentioned earlier "service", "price" and "faq" these are all post types as well and not categories or taxonomies?  Are there posts with the same name in the trash can?

Comment: Service - FAQ - and Price are all my custom post types

Comment: Any Other ideas? Im pretty sure its putting the number in because posts with the same name cant exist multiple times, but I want the posts to have the same name just in another post type

Comment: Posts with the same name can exist in different post types as I've tested it on several of my wordpress installations.  If you want to post a link I can try to take a look from the front end.  Did you check your trash can for each post type?  What I find confusing is that custom post type code you posted is for 'html5blank4' not service, faq or price, which is why I asked if these were categories.

Comment: I forgot to mention that if there are 'skincare' posts in the trash for each of these then you need to delete those permanently and then go and update the permalink of the existing skincare post.

Comment: here is the link: http://bellair.cidev.info

Comment: I have also posted my full code from my functions, maybe that will help!

Comment: So in summary, this code is creating the custom post types:
Services,
Prices,
FAQs,
Before and After

Comment: See my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535245/wordpress-custom-post-type-same-post-name-different-post-type/13535821#13535821 (where you posted your question again)

Comment: You are positive there are no duplicates in the trash?

Comment: Positive, I have cleared the trash in every custom post type

Comment: Could I see an example of how you do it?