# Wordpress Custom Post Type - Same Post Name, Different Post Type

Tags: wordpress

I have 4 Custom Post Types:

Services
FAQs
Prices
Before and After

I want to be able to have the same post names within each of these post types, example:

> Services
>   Skin (example.com/Services/skin)
>   Cream
>   (example.com/Services/cream)
>   Body (example.com/Services/body)
>
> FAQs
>   Skin (example.com/FAQs/skin)
>   Cream
>   (example.com/FAQs/cream)
>   Body (example.com/FAQs/body)
>
> Prices
>   Skin (example.com/Prices/skin)
>   Cream
>   (example.com/Prices/cream)
>   Body (example.com/Prices/body)
>
> Before and After
>   Skin (example.com/before-and-after/skin)
>   Cream
>   (example.com/before-and-after/cream)
>   Body (example.com/before-and-after/body)

How can I do this? Right now if I make a new post with the same name as a current one, it adds a "-2" or "-3" to the end of the posts slug:

BAD:

> example.com/services/body
>
> example.com/faqs/body-2
>
> example.com/prices/body-3
>
> example.com/before-and-after/body-4

SOMEONE PLEASE HELP!!!!!

```
add_action('init', 'create_post_type_html5'); // Add our HTML5 Blank Custom Post Type
function create_post_type_html5()
 {
  register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'html5-blank'); // Register Taxonomies for Category
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'html5-blank');
register_post_type('html5-blank', // Register Custom Post Type
    array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __('Services', 'html5blank'), // Rename these to suit
        'singular_name' => __('Services', 'html5blank'),
        'add_new' => __('Add New', 'html5blank'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Services', 'html5blank'),
        'edit' => __('Edit', 'html5blank'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Services', 'html5blank'),
        'new_item' => __('New Services', 'html5blank'),
        'view' => __('View Services', 'html5blank'),
        'view_item' => __('View Services', 'html5blank'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Services', 'html5blank'),
        'not_found' => __('No Servicess found', 'html5blank'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Service\'s found in Trash', 'html5blank')
    ),
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'service','with_front' => true),
    'public' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true, // Allows your posts to behave like Hierarchy Pages
    'has_archive' => true,
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'excerpt',
        'thumbnail'
    ), // Go to Dashboard Custom HTML5 Blank post for supports
    'can_export' => true, // Allows export in Tools > Export
    'taxonomies' => array(
        'post_tag',
        'category'
    ) // Add Category and Post Tags support
));


 }
```

Comment: [Didn't you post this same question yesterday?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518573/wordpress-custom-post-url-rewrite-numbers)

Comment: I did, but I dont think I framed it right... Im hoping this will attract more answers, I did a little more research

Comment: any ideas josh? Would greatly help me, Im pulling my hair out here lol

Comment: I don't, sorry. Just wanted to let you know that you should just edit your original post, as this one might be removed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a function that can be added to your theme's functions.php file that includes the patch written by mboynes in this ticket: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18962#comment:14

```
function wp_cpt_unique_post_slug($slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent, $original_slug) {
    if ( in_array( $post_status, array( 'draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft' ) ) )
        return $slug;

    global $wpdb, $wp_rewrite;

    // store slug made by original function
    $wp_slug = $slug;

    // reset slug to original slug
    $slug = $original_slug;

    $feeds = $wp_rewrite->feeds;
    if ( ! is_array( $feeds ) )
        $feeds = array();

    $hierarchical_post_types = get_post_types( array('hierarchical' => true) );
    if ( 'attachment' == $post_type ) {
        // Attachment slugs must be unique across all types.
        $check_sql = "SELECT post_name FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = %s AND ID != %d LIMIT 1";
        $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $check_sql, $slug, $post_ID ) );

        if ( $post_name_check || in_array( $slug, $feeds ) || apply_filters( 'wp_unique_post_slug_is_bad_attachment_slug', false, $slug ) ) {
            $suffix = 2;
            do {
                $alt_post_name = substr ($slug, 0, (200 - ( strlen( $suffix ) + 1 )) ) . "-$suffix";
                $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare($check_sql, $alt_post_name, $post_ID ) );
                $suffix++;
            } while ( $post_name_check );
            $slug = $alt_post_name;
        }
    } elseif ( in_array( $post_type, $hierarchical_post_types ) ) {
        if ( 'nav_menu_item' == $post_type )
            return $slug;
        // Page slugs must be unique within their own trees. Pages are in a separate
        // namespace than posts so page slugs are allowed to overlap post slugs.
        $check_sql = "SELECT post_name FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = %s AND post_type = %s AND ID != %d AND post_parent = %d LIMIT 1";
        $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $check_sql, $slug, $post_type, $post_ID, $post_parent ) );

        if ( $post_name_check || in_array( $slug, $feeds ) || preg_match( "@^($wp_rewrite->pagination_base)?\d+$@", $slug ) || apply_filters( 'wp_unique_post_slug_is_bad_hierarchical_slug', false, $slug, $post_type, $post_parent ) ) {
            $suffix = 2;
            do {
                $alt_post_name = substr( $slug, 0, (200 - ( strlen( $suffix ) + 1 )) ) . "-$suffix";
                $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $check_sql, $alt_post_name, $post_type, $post_ID, $post_parent ) );
                $suffix++;
            } while ( $post_name_check );
            $slug = $alt_post_name;
        }
    } else {
        // Post slugs must be unique across all posts.
        $check_sql = "SELECT post_name FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = %s AND post_type = %s AND ID != %d LIMIT 1";
        $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $check_sql, $slug, $post_type, $post_ID ) );

        if ( $post_name_check || in_array( $slug, $feeds ) || apply_filters( 'wp_unique_post_slug_is_bad_flat_slug', false, $slug, $post_type ) ) {
            $suffix = 2;
            do {
                $alt_post_name = substr( $slug, 0, (200 - ( strlen( $suffix ) + 1 )) ) . "-$suffix";
                $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $check_sql, $alt_post_name, $post_type, $post_ID ) );
                $suffix++;
            } while ( $post_name_check );
            $slug = $alt_post_name;
        }
    }

    return $slug;
}
add_filter('wp_unique_post_slug', 'wp_cpt_unique_post_slug', 10, 6);
```

Comment: In MY book, the above is THE answer - putting the solution in my functions makes it work a little smarter to me! Good job, Isabisa!

Comment: I tried it on Wordpress 4.2.2, it's not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is a bug not yet solved by wordpress programmer team.
Here are some other explanation about it : [Allow duplicate slugs for different content](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18962)

I found an uncorrect written code in this function: wp_unique_post_slug located in the core file (wp_includes/post.php) checking wether the permalink inserted is unique or not.

Unfortunately, I was forced to hack core code to fix the bug.
I've replaced this code portion started from line 2859:

```
} elseif ( in_array( $post_type, $hierarchical_post_types ) ) {
    // Page slugs must be unique within their own trees. Pages are in a separate
    // namespace than posts so page slugs are allowed to overlap post slugs.
    $check_sql = "SELECT post_name FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = %s AND post_type IN ( '" . implode( "', '", esc_sql( $hierarchical_post_types ) ) . "' ) AND ID != %d AND post_parent = %d LIMIT 1";
    $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $check_sql, $slug, $post_ID, $post_parent ) );

    if ( $post_name_check || in_array( $slug, $feeds ) || preg_match( "@^($wp_rewrite->pagination_base)?\d+$@", $slug )  || apply_filters( 'wp_unique_post_slug_is_bad_hierarchical_slug', false, $slug, $post_type, $post_parent ) ) {
        $suffix = 2;
        do {
            $alt_post_name = substr( $slug, 0, 200 - ( strlen( $suffix ) + 1 ) ) . "-$suffix";
            $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $check_sql, $alt_post_name, $post_ID, $post_parent ) );
            $suffix++;
        } while ( $post_name_check );
        $slug = $alt_post_name;
    }
}
```

with this code written by me:

```
} elseif ( in_array( $post_type, $hierarchical_post_types ) ) {

    // HACK
    foreach($hierarchical_post_types as $pt){

            // Page slugs must be unique within their own trees. Pages are in a separate
            // namespace than posts so page slugs are allowed to overlap post slugs.                                

            // HACK
            $check_sql_andrea = "SELECT post_name FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = %s AND post_type = %s AND ID != %d AND post_parent = %d LIMIT 1";
            // HACK
            $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $check_sql_andrea, $slug, $pt, $post_ID, $post_parent ) );

            if ( $post_name_check || in_array( $slug, $feeds ) || preg_match( "@^($wp_rewrite->pagination_base)?\d+$@", $slug )  || apply_filters( 'wp_unique_post_slug_is_bad_hierarchical_slug', false, $slug, $post_type, $post_parent ) ) {
                $suffix = 2;
                do {
                    $alt_post_name = substr( $slug, 0, 200 - ( strlen( $suffix ) + 1 ) ) . "-$suffix";
                    // HACK
                    $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $check_sql_andrea, $alt_post_name, $pt, $post_ID, $post_parent ) );
                    $suffix++;
                } while ( $post_name_check );
                $slug = $alt_post_name; 
                break;                          
            }
    }// END HACK

}
```

Please... Should anyone know any other solution to the case, or even more important should anyone know of any unpredictable consequence that would affect the solution I have found,please let me know, I would be really grateful!

Answer (score 0):

There is only one solution. Your posts need a unique identifier (slug) and cannot be named the same in the url. Except if they are hierarchical. And you can do that with custom post types. Use :

```
        register_post_type(
            'customposttype', 
            array(
                'label' => '...',
                'description' => '...',
                'public' => true,
                'exclude_from_search' => false,
                'hierarchical' => true, ...
```

Then you will be able to have identical names with different custom post types

Comment: I have hierarchical set to true, I will put an example of my custom post function

Comment: What should I change in my example, any ideas?

Comment: Can I possibly make a function that strips numbers and the last hyphen from slugs for certain custom post types?

Comment: You have to change your custom post type to make hierarchical, this is the only solution. Where is your custom post type declared? In functions.php? If so, provide the code and I'll give you the proper modifications. Or are you using a plugin to create the custom post types? even with a plugin, you should be able to specify if the post stype is hierarchical

Comment: Yes my custom post type declarations reside in functions.php, you can find the code in full here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518573/wordpress-custom-post-url-rewrite-numbers in my last (fairly similar lol) question

Answer (score 0):

I have searched for other references to this problem (it occurs too with [subcategories for different parent categories](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/duplicate-child-category-slug-in-wp-23?replies=6#post-729671)) and its even marked as [enhancement for future release](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18962), in that ticket, I've found a reference to function **wp_unique_post_slug** in wp-includes/post.php. Maybe you should take a look at it and spot a way to fix the current WP misbehavior.

A dirty solution could be re-checking the full slug output and if there is no duplicates, trim the numeric suffix added, but I'm pretty newbie *reading* WP source code to offer more advice into this.

Answer (score 0):

One solution may be to change your `rewrite` rules for `with_front` to false. For example, if you set

```
'rewrite => array( 
    'slug' => 'service',
    'with_front' => 'false'
)
```

you should be able to use the same categories/taxonomies in each one without conflicts.

Depending on what you're doing, you may have to define a unique taxonomy for each custom post type as well.

Answer (score 0):

Mind not to post different codes on the two questions you have sent.